# Prove the following:proving formula in predicate logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

(∀y)(∀x)(¬=∨=)→(∀x)(¬=∨=)

I am using Mathematical Logic by Dr. Tourlakis.
My try:

(∀x)(¬=∨=)

¬((∀y))(∀x)(¬=∨=) )∨(∀x)(¬=∨=) <1+A⊢B∨A>

(∀y)(∀x)(¬=∨=)→(∀x)(¬=∨=)<3+implication theorem +equation>

How can I prove this one ?
Is my answer correct and accurate to you?

Comment: You have only to instiate both quantifier of the premise with thes ame term $t$ and then use Unievrsal Generalization.

Comment: so did I do it right?  Mauro ALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

Assume the antecedent : $(∀y)(∀x)(\lnot (x=y) \lor x=y)$ and apply **Ax2** [page 139] : $(\forall x)A \to A[x := t]$ twice to get :

> $\lnot (t=t) \lor t=t$,

where term $t$ is *free for* $y$ and $x$ [see page 133 : every term different from $x$ and $y$ will do].

Then use **6.1.1 (Weak Generalization)** [page 155] to get :

> $(∀x)(\lnot (x=x) \lor x=x)$.

Finally, use **2.6.1 (Deduction Theorem)** [page 81].